# How would one solve Weibel 1.3.1 in a general Abelian category?

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory, homological-algebra, alternative-proof, diagram-chasing

Working through Weibel's Introduction to Homological Algebra, I am frequently unsure when it is acceptable to prove results using diagram-chasing and elements, and when Weibel has in mind a category-theoretic proof.

For example, [Weibel 1.3.1](https://books.google.com/books?id=flm-dBXfZ_gC&pg=PA11) asks for a proof of the claim:

> If $0 \rightarrow A_{\bullet} \xrightarrow{f} B_{\bullet} \xrightarrow{g} C_{\bullet} \rightarrow 0$ is a short exact sequence of chain complexes, then, whenever two of the three complexes $A_{\bullet}$,$B_{\bullet}$,$C_{\bullet}$ are exact, so is the third.

A complete solution using diagram chasing and elements is available [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32841/short-exact-sequence-of-exact-chain-complexes) However, the wording of the question, and the fact that Exercise 1.3.2 applies the result in a general Abelian category, suggest that a categorical proof is desired. How would such a proof go?

I understand that Freyd-Mitchell's Embedding Theorem implies that any theorems of a certain form which can be proven for R-modules using diagram chasing automatically hold in any Abelian category (Rotman calls this the Metatheorem). I suspect that this embedding should be "constructive" with respect to proofs.

My question is: Does there exist a concrete set of rules for lifting a proof by chasing elements into one by the equivalent category-theoretic properties? For example, how would one go about converting the following small excerpts in the diagram-chasing solution into language suitable for any Abelian category?

> Assume $B, C$ are exact and let $x \in \ker d \subseteq A_n$.
>   By commutative square we have
>   $$d(f_n(x)) = f_{n-1}(d(x)) = f_{n-1}(0) = 0$$
>   Thus $f_n(x) \in \ker d \subseteq B_n$, which is exactly $\operatorname{im} d \subseteq B_n$ by exactness of $B$, and there is some $b \in B_{n+1}$ such that $d(b) = f_n(x)$.
>
> . . .
>
> For $c \in C_{n+2}$ with $d(c) = g_{n+1}(b)$, since $g_{n+2}$ is surjective, there is some $b' \in B_{n+2}$ such that $g_{n+2}(b') = c$.
>
> Consider $b - d(b')$. We have by commutative square that $b - d(b') \in \ker g_{n+1}$:
>   $$g_{n+1}(b - d(b')) = g_{n+1}(b) - g_{n+1}(d(b')) = g_{n+1}(b) - d(g_{n+2}(b')) = g_{n+1}(b) - g_{n+1}(b) = 0$$

I think I understand how some small parts of this conversion would work. For example, you can replace statements like $\ker d = \operatorname{im} d$ with an isomorphism of their embeddings as submodules. But the step which constructs a difference of elements doesn't obviously seem to have a categorical equivalent.

Edit: 
As Pedro mentioned in a comment, the topic of converting element-proofs in $R\mathbf{-mod}$ or $\mathbf{Ab}$ into categorical proofs is discussed in [these](https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/papers/unpub/elem-chase.pdf) notes of Bergman, where he develops exactly this kind of dictionary of terms. The result seems somewhat more involved than I might hope for 1.3.1, so I'll leave open the restricted version of the question: is there an elementary categorical proof of Weibel 1.3.1 (stated above).

Comment: You can prove the snake lemma and then the existence of the LES in any abelian category, and then prove the 5 lemma, etc.

Comment: You are surely right, but Weibel places this exercise before any of that, which I suspect means it has a direct categorical proof. More generally, I'm curious about whether there exists a ``dictionary" between proof statements involving elements and their categorical counterparts.

Comment: See [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/element+in+an+abelian+category) for that. In particular the notes of Bergman :)

Comment: A first step would be to replace all inclusions with canonical morphisms making such and such diagrams commute ("thus $\mathrm{ker}d \subset B_n$" replaced with "we get a canonical morphism $\mathrm{ker}d \to B_n$ such that blabla commutes") - this will get you a long way

Comment: I can't believe you're doing this without pictures, at least in your writeup there are no pictures.  Category theory results are highly visual.  The app I'm writing is highly needed at this point in time.

Comment: @C.D. it is much easier, than you think. Using generalized elements you can literally repeat your proof $\textbf{word by word}$ for any abelian category, changing only $\in$ with $\in^*$ and $=$ with $=^*$. For more info see Handbok of Categorical Algebra 2, chapter Diagram Chasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it: ($B, C$ exact $\Rightarrow A$ is exact)

As per Weibel's notation, for a chain complex $C$, 
let $Z_{n}(C)$ and $B_{n}(C)$ denote the kernel and image of the morphisms $C_{n}\xrightarrow{d_{n}^{C}}C_{n-1}$ and $C_{n+1}\xrightarrow{d_{n+1}^{C}}C_{n}$ respectively. Then we have the factorization $C_{n+1}\twoheadrightarrow B_{n}(C) \hookrightarrow Z_{n}(C) \hookrightarrow C_{n}$ of the morphism $C_{n+1}\xrightarrow{d_{n+1}^{C}}C_{n}$,  which, for an exact complex, reduces to $C_{n+1}\twoheadrightarrow Z_{n}(C) \hookrightarrow C_{n}$.

In the proof I will use the fact that in any abelian category, the pullback of an epimorphism is an epimorphism. (See P.Freyd, *Abelian Categories*, Prop. 2.54 for a proof)

The map $A\xrightarrow{f}B$ induces morphisms $Z_{n}(A)\rightarrow Z_{n}(B)$ between the kernels. Consider the pullback diagram 
\begin{eqnarray}
E&\twoheadrightarrow& Z_{n}(A)\\
\downarrow &&\downarrow\\
B_{n+1}&\twoheadrightarrow&Z_{n}(B)
\end{eqnarray}
Here $E\twoheadrightarrow Z_{n}(A)$ is epi as $B_{n+1}\twoheadrightarrow Z_{n}(B)$ is. Now observe that $E\rightarrow B_{n+1} \xrightarrow{g_{n+1}}C_{n+1} \xrightarrow{d_{n+1}^{C}} C_{n}$ = $E \twoheadrightarrow Z_n(A) \hookrightarrow A_n \xrightarrow{f_n}B_n \xrightarrow{g_n} C_{n}$ = $E \xrightarrow{0} C_{n}$. Thus, by the universal property of the kernel $Z_{n+1}(C)$, there exists a unique morphism $E \dashrightarrow Z_{n+1}(C)$ such that $E \dashrightarrow Z_{n+1}(C) \hookrightarrow C_{n+1}$ = $E\rightarrow B_{n+1} \xrightarrow{g_{n+1}}C_{n+1}$. Consider the pullback diagram 
\begin{eqnarray}
P&\twoheadrightarrow& E\\
\downarrow &&\downarrow\\
B_{n+2}&\twoheadrightarrow&Z_{n+1}(C)
\end{eqnarray}
where the bottom morphism is the composition of the two epi's $B_{n+1} \xrightarrow{g_{n+2}} C_{n+2} \twoheadrightarrow Z_{n+1}(C)$. Let $r: P\rightarrow B_{n+1}$ be the composition $P\twoheadrightarrow E\rightarrow B_{n+1}$ and $s: P\rightarrow B_{n+1}$ be the composition $P\rightarrow B_{n+2} \xrightarrow{d_{n+2}^{B}} B_{n+1}$ and let $h = r-s$. Then, it is easy to see that $g_{n+1} \circ h = 0$. As $0\rightarrow A_{n+1} \xrightarrow{f_{n+1}} B_{n+1} \xrightarrow{g_{n+1}} C_{n+1}\rightarrow 0$ is a short exact sequence, $A_{n+1} \xrightarrow{f_{n+1}} B_{n+1}$ is the kernel of $B_{n+1} \xrightarrow{g_{n+1}} C_{n+1}$ and hence by the universal property of kernel, there exists a unique morphism $k: P \dashrightarrow A_{n+1}$ such that $f_{n+1}\circ k = h$. Composing with the morphism $B_{n+1} \xrightarrow{d_{n+1}^{B}} B_{n}$ we get $d_{n+1}^{B}\circ f_{n+1}\circ k = d_{n+1}^{B}\circ (r-s) = d_{n+1}^{B}\circ r$ which gives $P\xrightarrow{k}A_{n+1}\xrightarrow{d_{n+1}^{A}} A_n\xrightarrow{f_n}B_{n}$ = $P \twoheadrightarrow E\twoheadrightarrow Z_{n}(A) \hookrightarrow A_{n}\xrightarrow{f_n}B_{n}$. Since $f_n$ is a mono, we get $P\xrightarrow{k}A_{n+1}\xrightarrow{d_{n+1}^{A}} A_n$ = $P \twoheadrightarrow E\twoheadrightarrow Z_{n}(A) \hookrightarrow A_{n}$.

Composing with the epimorphism $A_n \twoheadrightarrow coker(d_{n+1}^{A})$, we get $P \twoheadrightarrow E\twoheadrightarrow Z_{n}(A) \hookrightarrow A_{n}\twoheadrightarrow coker(d_{n+1}^{A})$ = $P\xrightarrow{0} coker(d_{n+1}^{A})$ which implies $Z_{n}(A) \hookrightarrow A_{n}\twoheadrightarrow coker(d_{n+1}^{A})$ = $Z_{n}(A)\xrightarrow{0} coker(d_{n+1}^{A})$ (as $P \twoheadrightarrow E\twoheadrightarrow Z_{n}(A)$ is epi). Since by definition $B_{n}(A) \hookrightarrow A_{n}$ is the kernel of the morphism $A_n \twoheadrightarrow coker(d_{n+1}^{A})$, there exists a unique morphism $i: Z_{n}(A)\rightarrow B_{n}(A)$ such that $Z_{n}(A)\xrightarrow{i}B_{n}(A)\hookrightarrow Z_{n}(A)$ = $Z_{n}(A)\xrightarrow{id}Z_{n}(A)$ which implies that $i: Z_{n}(A)\rightarrow B_{n}(A)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I managed to understand it. But have to say it's super complicated.